# Can't create controller, dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I have the following Startup file (Startup.cs):

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{


    AutofacConfig.RegisterIoc();
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

    ConfigureOAuth(app); //This must come first before we load the WebApiConfig below.

    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    app.UseWebApi(config);

}
```

As you can see, I register the autofac config. The code for my autofac config looks like this:(AutofacConfig.cs)

```
 public class AutofacConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterIoc()
        {
            var builder = GetBuilder();
            var container = builder.Build();

            // Set dependency resolver for MVC
            //DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container));

            // Set dependency resolver for Web API
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        }

        public static ContainerBuilder GetBuilder()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            //builder.RegisterFilterProvider();


            var assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>().Where(x => x.FullName.Contains("API")).ToArray();
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .InstancePerRequest();

            return builder;
        }
    }
```

But when I run my application and tries to access a method in my controller, I get the following error:

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'DataController'. Make sure that the controller has a
>   parameterless public constructor.

I have tried to debug my startup.cs either to see if it's executed, and it does.

Before I used to register autofac in Global.asax, but because I use OAuth, I moved away from Global.asax and created a Startup-file instead. I guess it has something to do with this?

My controller look like this:

```
private readonly IItemModelService _itemModelService;

public DataController(IItemModelService itemModelService)
{
    this._itemModelService = itemModelService;
}
```

Stacktrace:

> at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type
>   instanceType)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)

Comment: It says you need a parameterless public constructor. You need `public DataController() { ... }`. Am I missing something?

Comment: You have to register service at container `container.RegisterType<IItemModelService  , ItemModelService >();`

Comment: Where are your IOC registrations?

Comment: @Div: No. Instead of doing that, Im just writing             var assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>().Where(x => x.FullName.Contains("API")).ToArray(); builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .InstancePerRequest();

Comment: @Progressive: They are in my autfacconfig.cs

Comment: Please add the stack trace.

Comment: @Steven: Check my updated question

Comment: I solved It. Check my updated question.

Comment: @Bryan If you have found the solution, then you can answer your own question! That way SO users will see that your question is already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Oauth with OWIN, and I did not know that It was a special implementation of autofac for owin based application.

My startup.cs looks like this and it works:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();


        //AutofacConfig.RegisterIoc();
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>().Where(x => x.FullName.Contains("API")).ToArray();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerRequest();

        var container = builder.Build();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        ConfigureOAuth(app); //This must come first before we load the WebApiConfig below.

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);

    }
```

I followed this links:

https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#owin-integration

https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/owin.html